# Unable to complete transaction using test account

Tags: testing, paypal

I'm unable to complete a transaction when my script connects to PayPal test environment.

The '**log in to complete your checkout**' page is where my problem occurs. I continue to receive an error message for the test buyer account.
'Please check your email address and password and try again'

The email and passwords for the test accounts I'm entering at this point are valid because I can log into each Sandbox account using them. I can view all of my Sandbox test accounts and my name is visible in the top right corner of the page as being actively logged in.
Can anyone figure out why my test accounts are not being recognized when I try to complete a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to indicate paypal your using sandbox?

```
$environment = 'sandbox';
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I think you pointed me in the right direction. It appears that when I was creating my test environment, Paypal generated a button that I pasted into my form that pointed to the regular Paypal site, not Sandbox. Changing the action attribute on the form to include Sandbox doesn't correct the problem. I think I need to generate a new button. I think I'm done with Paypal.

Comment: yes paypal can be frustrating sometimes.. Because you have a button I'm guessing that you want to test the return url?? if you login into paypal sandbox they have the option to test the IPN url. That would be the return url after somebody use your button. Maybe that's what you need.